# Select from database and store in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I want to select some data from db and store in an array. Suppose I have a column "keyword" in my db table. I want to select all rows where keyword column is like "nature".

I am trying following code:

```
<?
    $term= "nature";    
    $arr = array();

    $sql = "select keyword from keywords where keyword LIKE '%$term%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    foreach ($rows as $row){
            array_push($arr, $row['keyword']);
        }

    print_r($arr); //output: Array ( [0] => n [1] => n ) 

    ?>
```

So the result from db should return only one keyword 'nature' which i need to store in array.

1. Why it is storing same string two times? There is no any other row in db similar to the term nature.
2. Why it is storing only first letter in the array? Shouln't it store "nature" instead of "n"?

Please help me fixing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be something like

```
$term   = "nature";    
$arr    = array();
$sql    = "select keyword from keywords where keyword LIKE '%$term%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
 arr[] = $row[ 'keyword' ];
}
```

In your solution you only fetch the first record from the result-set as numeric indexed array.

Btw - you are aware that a LIKE-query starting with a wildcard cannot make use of any index?

Answer (score 3):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`